# asus laptop core i7 overheating

Tags: cpu, asus-laptop, intel-core-i7

I have asus N550JK laptop with core i7-4710hq, 16GB RAM, 7200 WD Black.
My laptop CPU temp is 50c in idle state and 70-90c in active state. I cleaned it, changed thermal paste, made a couple of holes in the bottom cover panel, no luck. The temperature is going down only if I take off bottom panel and add there 2 12 inch coolers from desktop case. Is it normal for this CPU? How long will it work in these conditions?

Comment: The max temp for this chip is 100°C - [Intel® Core™ i7-4710HQ Processor
(6M Cache, up to 3.50 GHz)](https://ark.intel.com/products/78930/Intel-Core-i7-4710HQ-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_50-GHz?q=i7-4710hq)

Comment: Yes I know, but is it ok that this cpu has temp 60c while cpu loading is 1-2% or 0? What it's doing in idle that it's temp is 60?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More advance technology meaning more heat they produce. Heat reducing efficiency of all component. Heat is weakness. Input from voltage produce output heat. Input=output. You cant resist heat when deal with electric components.

As you already know laptop got a plenty of room or space inside the equation of room chamber for the cooling. More advance technology product more heat and make laptop dealing with small account of room in cooling cycle loops effect while laptop component produce the same amount of desktop heat generally speaking in equality.

Heat temperature normal of idle after on the computer is about around 40c-44c while it depend on room of air cycling and cooling system. Laptop dont event have one except small fans. Most of todays laptop wont build for the biggest threats for the output efficiency rather than contribute to the technology itself which mean it is not balance of the todays R&D.

70c-90c while running is a huge amount of heat to deal with while cpu can stand the heat up to 105c before it shut down to counter the producing heat. Integrated circuit inside the cpu will be damaged by this heat thus reducing it life span.

You cant get away with this problem although you already take off or cut the air ventilation laptop case as i am. The heat will effect the motherboard and screen display until one day you will get a black screen plus heat with the graphic card itself(NVIDIA GeForce GTX 850M). Wifi card will also contribute the heat when you connect to the wifi which will deal amount total of heat around plus minus to the total of heat the already product from cpu. The motherboard will blow up when this continuation of usage reducing the life span if laptop. For my experience you will experienced failure on 1 and a half year after purchased new laptop before the failure start to begin. As you got 1 years warranty, you may go on and of to the store to redeem warranty. Limited Warranty period (parts): 1 year
Limited Warranty period (labor): 1 year

In the circuit got capacitor and almost of the time capacitor is the main culprit inside the laptop failure technical part.

I believe on my experience on Asus, it got a better mobo rather any other brand.

If you buy laptop, you cant dealt with this normal issue. Suggest you get desktop as money involve particularly same amount in diff. Dont play games if the most efficient to max its life span. Connect laptop with plug cord rather the battery to limit the heat produce. Dont charge laptop while in use. Put small amount of contrast and brightness to display as this connected to nvidia itself for graphic display. Shut down computer after 5-10minutes to let all heat produced dissipated before put in the bag.

I believe i answered your question so far additional info on my exp to the laptop mech.

Comment: Thank you, in other words laptop can't be a replacement for desktop for heavy tasks like virtual machines, development, etc? This laptop in 1.5 years of use and it was running 24/7 for some months for heavy tasks. Now in idle state it's temp 55c. Is it a sign that it's lifetime is running out?